# Yes/No Column default value not set

Tags: 2013, site-column, default-value

I have a yes/no column with a default value of **No**.  This column is defined at the site collection level and is first included in a content type which is the parent content type of several others.  These children content types are all added to a document library.  There is a default content type defined on the list.

For almost all of the items uploaded to this document library, the default value for the column is set.  Recently, I had four failures for it to be set.  For these four documents, the column was set to *(blank)*.

The end user does not have the ability to set it himself (it is created as part of a document imaging workflow).  I cannot replicate the issue myself.  It happens so rarely (four times out of about 6200 items) that I'm not sure how it happened at all.

Is there a way to further reinforce this default value being set?  How do I go about diagnosing exactly where this blank came from?  Is it even possible for a yes/no column to be set as not yes or not no?

Comment: Not sure how the column could not be set to No, if it has a default value. Is it a required field? I would say try column validation, but if it is being set by a workflow, that isn't going to help...

Comment: I tried doing the required field route also, but the option was grayed out all the way down to its definition.  Thanks for the idea!